# Is it a good idea to have multiple jobs in one stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

What is the best practice about this situation?

I want to do multiple DIFFERENT operations on a single entity in my database.I want to insert data, delete rows and etc(basic functionalities only) and I was wondering if it is a good idea to do all of them in one stored procedure using a flag parameter like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_entity
    @flag INT
    @id AS INT = 0
    @field AS VARCHAR = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF @flag = 1
    INSERT INTO entity (field) VALUES (@field)
    ELSE IF @flag = 2
    DELETE FROM entity WHERE id = @id
END
```

Or is it better to create different stored procedures like `ups_entity_insert` and `usp_entity_delete` to accomplish these tasks?

The reason I am asking this is because one of our teachers did the first approach the other day and I am not sure if it is the right way

Comment: Ask yourself this question. "Would you do this in a single method in your programming code?" The answer should be, "of course not, that is ridiculous.". You wouldn't create a method to insert, update and delete in your object so why should you do it in the database?

Comment: This question is "primary opinion based" not a good fit for [so].

Comment: If you believe in the [Single Responsability Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of software design, then definitely **NO**

Comment: @marc_s Either way it's all opinion *(surprised it's [not been closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to be honest)*, some like to do CRUD together others don't we could argue the point all day, one thing I do agree with that anything more complex then CRUD should be separated into separate stored procedures.

Comment: If you do anything like this, please remember that query plan is created on the first execution for **all** the parts of your procedure. If you have variables that do not get the value in every execution because it's related to the other operation, you might get really bad performance too.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to do multiple DIFFERENT operations on a single entity in my
>   database.I want to insert data, delete rows and etc(basic
>   functionalities only) and I was wondering if it is a good idea to do
>   all of them in one stored procedure using a flag parameter like this:

I would not do this.  It is less clear to people who inherit your code down the road about what it actually does.  Making different stored procedures named appropriately is way easier to maintain and is more descriptive to other people.

> Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you live. - Martin Golding

Security is another reason to keep them separate.  If you place multiple operations in one procedure, it's an all or nothing approach.  Many times certain applications need to read data, but I don't want them to update or maybe insert.  There are other times when I need to delete data, but I really want to control who has access to that.

Comment: Generally speaking Kevin is absolutely correct - make your code as succinct and descriptive as possible, within a tightly defined scope.  Some will argue that it's "just a simple application" or "I only need this one proc".  The problem with that mentality is that when the scope starts to creep or you need additional code, most won't take the time to fix the first couple of simple crappy procs.

Comment: I'm a big fan of stored procedures to do CRUD operations, why should a stored procedure have to be modelled individually to do CRUD operations when you can easily build one that will do the lot. As long as it is well documented and appropriately commented what's the issue?

Comment: @Lankymart . . . If you are wrapping multiple exclusive operations in a single stored procedure, then the issue is compilation of the queries in SQL Server.  Naively implementing such a solution might result in difficult-to-find inefficiencies.

Comment: I must admit I've always approached stored procedures as a Programmer rather then a DBA, might not be the best approach but served me well so far.

Comment: Honestly, I separate them out, because I've approached them as a programmer.  I think of each procedure just like I would a function in a program and believe they should follow the Single Responsibility Principle.  I also treat them like APIs, because I have no idea who might call them in the future, so I like to be explicit in what they do, and try and leave no room for mistakes (like passing the wrong flag and accidentally modifying data).

Comment: There is always room for mistakes even when you think you have all your bases covered.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, this is probably a bad idea.  SQL Server compiles all the queries in a stored procedure the first time it is run.  Using a flag to distinguish among different code paths can result in inefficient execution plans for the remaining queries.

Of course, having multiple queries in a stored procedure is a *good* idea if the queries are related.  In general, you want to think of a stored procedure as "doing something", often encapsulating multiple steps.  So, you might want to:

- Log that an action is being taken
- Insert rows into one table
- Update rows in another table
- and so on

These are all "one thing", so they belong together.

Also, in SQL Server, never use `varchar` without a length parameter.  The default varies by context and this can cause errors that are hard to find.  And, don't compare a `varchar` to an integer.  Mixing types is confusing for a human reader and can sometimes confuse the optimizer as well.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the varchar data type.I simply forgot to define a range for it since I was typing in the question's editor.But thank you for the information

Answer (score 3):

In general this is called CRUD. Basic actions performed over any entity: **create**, **read**, **update**, **delete**. In your example you have two scenarios: for insert and for delete; also it may include regular update work - I think this is absolutely okay to have these operations within one SP since all three of them are:

1. DML
2. perform actions based on specific single record
3. do not return any dataset.

Including here **read** operation I think would be a mistake - SP then would sometimes return resultset sometimes not - which is obviously a confusing behavior.

Other option is to have *three* SPs (I don't mention here *read* operation) for every action: one for insert, one for update, one for delete. This does not sound wrong until you multiply it on amount of entities. Let's say you have 500 entities which means you have 1500 CrUD SPs. Or only 500 CrUD SPs.

If you have separate SPs for insert/update/delete then you probably have to copy and paste parameter validation code, calls to logging and checking permissions SPs and so on. While there is still only one unique statement and all the rest is similar.

Update and Delete are usually performed on single record, Insert values does not have select part so I don't see any troubles with execution plan or something. And note that SQLSERVER can recompile separate statement instead of recompiling full SP since mssql2005 if I'm not mistaken.

To have SP on each operation is okay too, the only trouble you will possibly have - the number of SPs. If you produce them with code-generation tool or any kind of ORM so this work is well automated (remember refactoring, including some "low-level" work like logging/tracing/security/business rules/validation) then of course there is no need to think of number of SPs and may be it will even be more comfortable to have separate SP on every action.

And, of course, if your SPs are very smart, have tons of code for every scenario then as you can understand it yourself it would be easier to maintain them separately. Because else it would be simply hard to understand'em.

And again, including code for rather different purposes is a horrible idea that has no excuses.